# Plotting random slopes from glmer model using sjPlot

Tags: r, graphics, sjplot

In the past, I had used the `sjp.glmer` from the package [sjPlot](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/sjPlot/sjPlot.pdf) to visualize the different slopes from a generalized mixed effects model. However, with the new package, I can't figure out how to plot the individual slopes, as in the figure for the probabilities of fixed effects by (random) group level, located [here](https://strengejacke.wordpress.com/2014/11/18/visualizing-generalized-linear-mixed-effects-models-part-2-rstats-lme4/)

Here is the code that, I think, should allow for the production of the figure. I just can't seem to get it in the new version of `sjPlot`.

```
library(lme4)
library(sjPlot)
data(efc)
# create binary response
efc$hi_qol = 0
efc$hi_qol[efc$quol_5 > mean(efc$quol_5,na.rm=T)] = 1
# prepare group variable
efc$grp = as.factor(efc$e15relat)
# data frame for 2nd fitted model
mydf <- na.omit(data.frame(hi_qol = as.factor(efc$hi_qol),
                           sex = as.factor(efc$c161sex),
                           c12hour = as.numeric(efc$c12hour),
                           neg_c_7 = as.numeric(efc$neg_c_7),
                           grp = efc$grp))
# fit 2nd model
fit2 <- glmer(hi_qol ~ sex + c12hour + neg_c_7 + (1|grp),
              data = mydf,
              family = binomial("logit"))
```

I have tried to graph the model using the following code.

```
plot_model(fit2,type="re")
plot_model(fit2,type="prob")
plot_model(fit2,type="eff")
```

I think that I may be missing a flag, but after reading through the documentation, I can't find out what that flag may be.

Comment: just to clarify: you're talking about  `type = "ri.prob"` from the linked blog post? And can you specify what you've tried & what's not working?

Comment: I am talking about the plot type = "ri.prob". I will edit my question to show what I have tried.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Looks like this might do what you want:

```
(pp <- plot_model(fit2,type="pred",
       terms=c("c12hour","grp"),pred.type="re"))
```

- `type="pred"`: plot predicted values
- `terms=c("c12hour", "grp")`: include `c12hour` (as the x-axis variable) and `grp` in the predictions
- `pred.type="re"`: random effects

I haven't been able to get confidence-interval ribbons yet (tried `ci.lvl=0.9`, but no luck ...)

`pp+facet_wrap(~group)` comes closer to the plot shown in the linked blog post (each random-effects level gets its own facet ...)

[image]

Comment: I'm using your code here: http://bbolker.github.io/mixedmodels-misc/glmmFAQ.html#predictions-andor-confidence-or-prediction-intervals-on-predictions to compute conf. int. or pred. int. for mixed models, however, I'm not sure how this might work when plotting specific levels of random effects, to get the CI / PI for the random effects.

Answer (score 3):

Ben already posted the correct answer. sjPlot uses the [ggeffects-package](https://strengejacke.github.io/ggeffects) for marginal effects plot, so an alternative would be using ggeffects directly:

```
ggpredict(fit2, terms = c("c12hour", "grp"), type="re") %>% plot()
```

There's [a new vignette](https://strengejacke.github.io/ggeffects/articles/randomeffects.html) describing how to get marginal effects for mixed models / random effects. However, confidence intervals are currently not available for this plot-type.

The `type = "ri.prob"` option in the linked blog-post did not adjust for covariates, that's why I first removed that option and later re-implemented it (correctly) in ggeffects / sjPlot. The confidence intervals shown in the linked blog-post are not correct, either. Once I figure out a way how to obtain CI or prediction intervals, I'll add this option as well.

Comment: Is it possible to exp() the predicted values and the confidence intervals so instead of getting lines, get the curves ? I have been trying to use the transform inside the ggpredict but I keep having non parallel lines

Comment: No, it's only possible to plot predictions on the response scale. However, you may try [`modelbased::estimate_link()`](https://easystats.github.io/modelbased/reference/estimate_expectation.html) to plot predictions on the link-scale.