# Interpreting and plotting piecewise lme regression (sjPlot)

Tags: r, data-visualization, spline

I am running a LME (Linear Mixed-Effects regression) in R where the knot is determined by the time of diagnosis (t=0). So the model is now:

```
lme(function ~ age+sex+timepre*marker+timepost*marker, random=~time|ID, data=data)
```

Thus: timepre is where everything from t=0 is 0 and before that is 0-time, and timepost is where everything before diagnosis is 0 and afterwards is 0+time.
The time is the combination of timepre and timepost.

I now wanted to plot these effects using the sjPlot library as it nicely gives the predicted values (corrected for covariates) and having this as a plot where one could see the knot at t=0.

```
plot_model(model, type="int")
```

Instead it is plotting two different plots, one for each interaction. Is there a way to combine these plots, so that the slopes before and after come together (the intercepts are also different now)? Or how should I do this?

[image]

UPDATE:

After googling more, I found a suggestion to use splines instead of two separate time frames. 
So, what I tried now is:

```
lme(function ~ age+sex+bs(time, knots=0, degree=1)*marker, random=~time|ID, data=data)
```

I am able to plot this with the visreg library and I do seem to get the knot at zero:

[image]

Is this correct?
Am I correct that the coefficients should be interpreted as follows:

```
bs(time, knots = 0, degree = 1)1:marker  12.055090  p= 0.0004
bs(time, knots = 0, degree = 1)2:marker  13.750058  p= 0.0133
```

the first coeff (12.055 and with p-value 0.0004) represents the change in the first slope (before the knot) as a function of the level of the marker?
And the second coeff (13.75 with p-value 0.013) represents the difference between the first and second slope as a function of the marker?
How then to know if change in the second slope is significant as a function of the marker?

Comment: This looks like it has some good info on interpretation: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37362738/how-to-interpret-lm-coefficient-estimates-when-using-bs-function-for-splines

Comment: Thank you, but I think it is harder in the context of an interaction? Any suggestions on interpreting these coefficients with an interaction?

Comment: Aren't you actually looking for a single interaction of a pre-post dummy variable with marker and then plotting the random slopes (e.g., https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53855738/plotting-random-slopes-from-glmer-model-using-sjplot)?

Comment: Hi Dominix, that was my initial goal, as that is how I was taught piecewise linear regression, but when plotting it, the lines of pre and post don't connect (intercept of post is incorrect I think) and I am not sure how to get the plotting. Any thoughts on that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to use splines for your time variable, especially if you just have two time points, you can't fit any curve between these two points. Thus, your model would be:

```r
lme(function ~ age + sex + time * marker, random=~time|ID, data=data)
```

You can then use `plot_model(model, type = "int")` to see the interaction and differences between the two time points. Or you can use the **ggeffects** package, which is even a bit more flexible.

If the `time` variable has more than two time points, it probably makes sense using `poly()` or splines. For **ggeffects**, there's a practical example including polynomial terms [here](https://strengejacke.github.io/ggeffects/articles/practical_logisticmixedmodel.html) (and a general introduction [here](https://strengejacke.github.io/ggeffects/articles/practical_logisticmixedmodel.html)).

For your above example:

```r
library(ggeffects)
m <- lme(function ~ age+sex+bs(time, knots=0, degree=1)*marker, random=~time|ID, data=data)
pred <- ggpredict(m, c("time", "marker"))
plot(pred)
```

Comment: Hi Daniel, Thank you, this visualization works great. I indeed have more than two time points (6 before time points and 3 after the marker). Do you have suggestions on how to interpret the coeff with the spline interactions? I am still struggling, both splines (1 and 2) are significant:
bs(time, knots = 0, degree = 1)1     -15.951946  p=0.0004
bs(time, knots = 0, degree = 1)2     -18.440233  p=0.0124
marker                                   -7.794002  p=0.0061
bs(time, knots = 0, degree = 1)1:marker  12.055090  p=0.0004
bs(time, knots = 0, degree = 1)2:marker  13.750058  p=0.0133

Comment: Coefficients from splines are difficult to interprete, that's why I would always use effect-plots to visualize the model-results.

Comment: Depending on your plot, you may already see from the confidence intervals if they overlap or not. If they don't, this may indicate a significant difference - but not necessarily. You can also adjust for multiple comparisons, using the emmeans package using `pairwise()`.